# creating a role based authentication system in Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, authentication, jdbc

I am writing a software on java that connects to postgres db via jdbc. How can I create an authentication system so that user can connect to db with a predefined db role and create tables that will have a reference to this user?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the username, authentication type, database name and the server IP from where you are connecting in the `pg_hba.conf` file of postgresql database cluster.

If you want the user to be authenticated from that ip automatically, mention the authentication type as trust, or ypu will have to create a `.pgpass` file mentioning the username and its credential in it.